# grayscale image rotation with cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation, image-rotation

I'm trying to crop and rotate an grayscale image.
The image is being rotated successfully according to my defined dimensions, but the intensity channel seems to get zeroed up across the entire rotated image.

**image** - the original 32,000X1024X1 grayscale image.

**i** - an index from which I want to crop the image.

**windowWidth** - a size constant, which defines the number of pixels I wish to crop (e.g in our case, windowWidth = 5000).

**cropped** - the piece from the original image I wish to rotate.

code example:

```py
cropped = image[i:i+windowWidth, :]
ch, cw = cropped.shape[:2]
rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cw/2,ch/2),90,1)
return cv2.warpAffine(cropped,rotation_matrix, (ch,cw))
```

The returned 1024X5000X1 matrix contains only 0's, although the original image does not.

Comment: what value of 'i' you are using?

Comment: Please include `cropped`, so we may reproduce the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: `warpAffine` seems a bit of an overkill for a 90 degree rotation. I'd go with [`np.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) or [`cv.rotate`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4ad01c0978b0ce64baa246811deeac24) instead.

Comment: i=0 at the first iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that you are using width instead of height, then maybe this would solve your problem:

`cropped = image[:, i:i+windowWidth]`